# Python: How can I use if else statement on re.search?

Tags: python

How to make if else on this example.

If it finds 'spam-egg' print success, else print 'error'

```
m = re.search('(?<=-)\w+', 'spam-egg')
m.group(0)
```

Comment: After calling `re.search` you **must** check if `m` is `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.search` returns `None` if there is no match.

```
m = re.search(r'(?<=-)\w+', 'spam-egg')
if m:
    print(m.group(0))
else:
    print('error')
```

Notice also the use of an `r'...'` string to properly pass through the backslash to the regex compiler. (Works fine in this case, but don't depend on it.)

Comment: I have a response that 'm' is not defined